# Jquery : Removing row not working properly

Tags: jquery

My code implements like this :

A dialog box is shown when delete button of any row is clicked.Then if OK button is clicked, this row gets deleted but if Cancel button is clicked then the dialog box disappears and this row is not deleted.

My problem is that after clicking cancel button then after that if I delete any other row then the previous row (at which I clicked cancel button ) also gets deleted.

My code is :

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/development-bundle/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.button.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/development-bundle/demos/demos.css">
<script>
$(function() {

$('#b1').click(function(){
$( "#dialog" ).css('visibility','visible');
$( "#dialog" ).dialog();
$('#bt1').click(function(){
  $('#r1').remove();
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog('close');   
  });
});

$('#b2').click(function(){
$( "#dialog" ).css('visibility','visible');
$( "#dialog" ).dialog();
$('#bt1').click(function(){
  $('#r2').remove();
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog('close');   
  });
});

$('#b3').click(function(){
$( "#dialog" ).css('visibility','visible');
$( "#dialog" ).dialog();
$('#bt1').click(function(){
  $('#r3').remove();
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog('close');   
  });
});

    $('#bt2').click(function(){
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog('close');   
  });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dialog" title="Confirmation Box" style="visibility:hidden;">
    <p>Are you sure that you want to perform this action ?</p>
<input type="button" value="OK" id="bt1">&nbsp&nbsp
<input type="button" value="Cancel" id="bt2">
</div>
<table cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="5px" border="1px">
<tr>
<th>Name
<th>Roll No
<th>Delete
<tr id="r1">
<td>Reena
 <td>9/cs117
<td><input type="button" value="Delete" id="b1">
<tr id="r2">
<td>Ajay
<td>10/cs47
<td><input id="b2" type="button" value="Delete">
<tr id="r3">
<td>Meeta
<td>11/cs72
<td><input id="b3" type="button" value="Delete">
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you made listener inside each function. So even you though clicked cancel button the listener will fire whenever you click button with id "bt1".

The solution

create separate method to delete row like below.

```
$('#bt1').click(function(){ $('#'+v).remove(); $( "#dialog" ).dialog('close');});
```

Inside all the other methods just assign a value like r1,r2,r3 for a variable v.

```
v='r2';
```

That's all. Make sure to declare a variable v on the top of all methods.

```
$(function() {var v=null;
```

Sample method

```
$('#b2').click(function(){$( "#dialog" ).css('visibility','visible');$( "#dialog" ).dialog();v='r2';});
```

Comment: If this works fine, Make this answer correct by clicking the tick mark. Will be useful for others.

Comment: Can you tell me version of jquery ui that is compatible with jquery tablesorter version 2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

You should try to fix your HTML-table. I know closing td's/tr's are optional, but it can cause errors if you don't add them. [Read this](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/qt/optional-html-end-tags-when-to-include-them.htm)

```
<table cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="5px" border="1px">
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Roll No</th>
<th>Delete</th>
</tr>
<tr id="r1">
<td>Reena</td>
 <td>9/cs117</td>
<td><input type="button" value="Delete" id="b1"></td></tr>
<tr id="r2">
<td>Ajay</td>
<td>10/cs47</td>
<td><input id="b2" type="button" value="Delete"></td></tr>
<tr id="r3">
<td>Meeta</td>
<td>11/cs72</td>
<td><input id="b3" type="button" value="Delete"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have tried this .But still it is working in the previous way.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code

```
<body>  
 <table cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="5px" border="1px">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th> 
        <th>Roll No</th> 
        <th>Delete</th> 
    </tr>
    <tr id="r1">
        <td>Reena</td> 
        <td>9/cs117</td> 
        <td>
        <input class="btnDelete" type="button" value="Delete" id="b1" /></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr id="r2">
        <td>Ajay</td> 
        <td>10/cs47</td> 
        <td><input class="btnDelete" id="b2" type="button" value="Delete"/></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr id="r3">
        <td>Meeta</td> 
        <td>11/cs72</td> 
        <td><input class="btnDelete" id="b3" type="button" value="Delete"/></td> 
    </tr>
  </table>
 </body>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
            $('td input.btnDelete').click(function () {
                $("#dialog").css('visibility', 'visible');
                var tr = $(this).closest('tr');

                $('#bt1').click(function () {
                    tr.remove();
                    $("#dialog").css("visibility", "hidden");
                });

            });

            $('#bt2').click(function () {
                $("#dialog").css("visibility", "hidden");
            });
        });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#b1").click(function(){$(function () {
                    $('#dialog').dialog({

                        resizable: false,
                        modal: true,
                        width: "auto",
                        height: "auto",
                        buttons: {
                            "Yes":  {
                                text: "Yes",
                                id: "ConfirmDel",
                                click: function () {
                                    $('#ConfirmDel').click(function(){

                                      //Do your code here 
                                            $(this).dialog('close');
                                  });
                                  }
                                  },
                            "No":
                                  {
                                    text:"No",
                                    id:"NoDel",
                                    click:function () { $(this).dialog('close'); }
                                  }
  }

})
})
```